# Java Script Type Error while adding Stock Chart to GWT SimplePanel

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I am trying to add a Stock Chart to a GWT Simple Panel. The Stock Chart has Categories [Date Values Represented as Strings] and YSeries Values [Number [] Array List]. I require help in resolving the Java Script Type error.

Code Looks like this:

```
    public void createStockChart(String[] categories,
            List<Number[]> Yseries, String[] seriesNames) {
        if (StkChart == null) {
            String xAxisTitle = "Date Range";
            String yAxisTitle = "Count Values";
            StkChart = new StockChart();
            StkChart.setTitle("Avg Performance");
            StkChart.setType(Series.Type.LINE);
            StkChart.getXAxis().setAxisTitleText(xAxisTitle, true);
            StkChart.getXAxis().setType(Axis.Type.LINEAR);
            StkChart.getYAxis().setAxisTitleText(yAxisTitle, true);
            StkChart.getXAxis().setCategories(true, categories);
            StkChart.setShadow(true);
            StkChart.setSize(550, 300);

            for (int index = 0; index < Yseries.size(); index++) {
                StkChart.addSeries(StkChart.createSeries()
                        .setPoints(Yseries.get(index))
                        .setName(seriesNames[index]));
            }

            StkChart.getXAxis().setLabels(new XAxisLabels().setStep(2));
            ChartPnl.add(StkChart); [Java Script Exception occurs here]
        }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
17:46:58.437 [ERROR] [myapp] Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(536), JavaScript object(199), JavaScript object(539)]): undefined is not a function

at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:570)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:278)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The stack trace you've posted is unfortunately missing some details, but that has to do with how gwt traps this kind of error. The code is also not giving enough details: What is ChartPnl, and how did you create it? What is StkChart? The code you've posted seems to be just a very small window into your app, and there isn't enough visible to suggest where to look next...

Comment: Thanks. StkChart is instance of GWT HighCharts.StockChart() and ChartPnl is a Ui Field representing a GWT Simple Panel. This is a small wrapper around Stock Chart utility to pass the categories and Series Data. I call this method from my application to display a Chart. This is the complete exception that I get. I will recheck the same. I would like to know how to resolve "Undefined is not a function" Java Script Exception. Please let me know if any other information that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed the below step.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highstock.js"></script>
```

Had added the wrong JS file earlier.

http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/apidocs/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that one of the variables you pass to createStockChart is null or empty.

Comment: I have verified. All the values I pass contain values. In the chart object, I see the categories, series, xAxes, yAxes values set. The problem occurs only when I try adding this chart to the simple Panel.

Comment: Did you try FlowPanel or HtmlPanel instead of SimplePanel?

Comment: Yes. I continue to get the same error. In addition I have also checked that i have the necessary jquery.js file added in the js path.

Comment: Sorry for the needless Confusion. I had missed the appropriate JS file in the HTML. Thanks for the input and suggestions.